# What is the size of a page table entry in a multi level page table?

Tags: memory, operating-system

I understand why a multi-level page table saves memory. In the classic 32-bit example, the size of each Page Table Entry (PTE) in a single-level table is 32 bit (4 Bytes). The fact that 20 of the 32 bits are used for page number means there are 2^20 (~1M) possible entries in this table. The total size of a single-level table is therefore 4 Bytes * 1M = 4MB.A two-level page table requires less memory because it does not need all of the second-level pages at the same time.

However, in a lot of examples for the calculations of two-level page table on the internet, people still use 4 Bytes to indicate the size of each PTE. Since we are only accessing 10 of the 32 bits at the first level, shouldn't the size of these PTEs be smaller than 4 Bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual address is broken to `10-10-12` first 10 bits are an index in the first level page table, there, you will find the address of the second level page table, which you index with the seconds 10 bits to find the start of the physical frame which you index with the remaining 12 bits.

Actually each entry contains the number of the virtual page (there are 2^20 such pages) and 12 flag bits.

Comment: Do you mean that we are still accessing the whole of the 32 bits even if we are just looking at the first 10 bits to work out where the second-level page is?

Comment: @ShimmyShimmyYa the 10 bits in the original address are just an index in the page table. There you have a memory address which is 32 bits. (actually 20 + 12 flag bits).